# Category collection returns a different results

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.2

I have a category where is_active = 0, include_in_menu = 0 and url = test. But the category has Url Rewrite Rule and final url = test_new.

If I get category data from observer (event - after save category in admin panel) using Category Factory, I get incorrect url (url = test, but needs url = test_new).

If I get category data in other place, I get incorrect is_active and include_in_menu, but url - correct.

I use this code in both places:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;

...

protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
}

public function test () {
    $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

    $collection
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['eq' => $object->getEntityId()])
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addUrlRewriteToResult();

    $items = [];
    if (!empty($collection->getItems())) {
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $category) {
            $items[] = $category;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get correct all data and url with all Url Rewrites Rule for my category?